# Google Video intelligence - Billing by segments

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

Do you know when we send a request with segments list
(https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/rest/v1/videos/annotate#VideoContext)
to analyse, if we are only charged for the segments times or the all video
duration ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify video-segments on your request, then only those segments will be analyzed and you will only be charged for the analyzed video. As you can see in [pricing official docs](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/pricing) you are billed per minute and not per video:

> Prices are per minute

The different [features that can be analyzed using VideoIntelligence](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/features) will work only on video-segments if you provide them:

1. Label detection:

> A LABEL_DETECTION request annotates ...entities ...detected ... in video segments provided

2. Shot change detection:

> Shot detection ...detects changes...that occur throughout the length of... video segment.

3. Explicit content detection

> EXPLICIT_CONTENT_DETECTION request annotates...entities ...detected in...video segments provided

Comment: Make sense, i wanted a confirmation. Thank You!